# Neat 2.0 Grid - media queries

Tags: bourbon, neat

I'm trying to follow the examples for the media query bases Neat grid [here](https://codepen.io/herrjosuab/pen/PadELx), but I'm having trouble getting the media queries to run. I'm able to get the `tablet` and `phone` ones to work, but I can not get the `desktop` version to run. I have included the code and screenshots below:

**SCSS**

```
@import "../bourbon/bourbon";
@import "../neat/neat";

// Set a default grid.
$neat-grid: (
    columns: 12, // define some columns to match your mockup.
    gutter: 12px, // adjust gutters to match your mockup.
);

// Create a breakpoint.

$desktop: (
    columns: 12,
    media: 1280px,
);

$tablet-portrait: (
    columns: 8,
    media: 991px,
);

$phone-portrait: (
    columns: 6,
    media: 578px,
);

// This is "the grid" container.
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
}

// A row contains columns. grid-container creates a clearfix.
.row {
    @include grid-container;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Media Queries (<a href="http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/latest/#grid-media">link</a>)</h2>
<p class="note">Squish the viewport to see this in action!</p>
<div class="container container-media-queries">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><pre>Test</pre></div>
        <div class="col"><pre>Test</pre></div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container-media-queries -->
```

Desktop view
[image: Desktop]

Tablet View
[image: Tablet]

Phone View
[image: Phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't quite enough information here but it seems as though the confusion lies in the fact that the default behavior of the `grid-media` mixin is to be mobile first. That means that the media query that it generates will be some thing like `@media (min:width XXXpx) {…}` meaning it only activates at that dimension or *larger*. Check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat.bourbon.io/blob/master/source/assets/stylesheets/examples/article-layout.scss for reference

Comment: I have a quick follow-on question. I was able to get the example working using the code above, but I'm not sure how I would control the number of columns the sidebar would span. It is currently just taking up 40% of the available space. How would I add Presentational Classes to control the spacing, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: he `grid-column()` mixin controls how far an element should expand https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat.bourbon.io/blob/master/source/assets/stylesheets/examples/article-layout.scss#L28 In this case there are a total of 5 columns. it has `@include grid-column(2);`. 2 / 5 ends up as 40%

If you're just getting started, give this a read https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-release-of-neat-2-0-a-lightweight-and-flexible-sass-grid